How can I save the photo that the user has changed?
I have a picture that I divided into different areas, when the user clicks on each area, a cross appears on that area. I did this with html and javascript.
Now I want this photo to be saved with its changes when the save button is clicked.
My environment is Oracle Apex.
How can I do this?
